# Calling Qml function From JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function, qml

I am developing an app using Qt and I am stuck at one point where I want to call QML function from JavaScript on a particular event which is fired from my HTML.

I have tried the following approach:

app.html

```
<html>
<head><title>Myapp</title></head>
<script src="testjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body bgcolor="orange">
<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction1()">Click me to change my text color.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

testjs.js

```
function myFunction1() {
    alert("alert");
    someComponent.someSlot(30);
    someComponent.someSlot(31);
}
```

main.qml

```
import 'testjs.js' as JavascriptObject


ApplicationWindow {
    id: someComponent
    visible: true
    x: initialX
    y: initialY
    width: initialWidth
    height: initialHeight
    title: webView.title

    WebView {
        id: webView
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: initialUrl
    }
    function someSlot(v) {
        console.log("Signal received " + v);
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        JavascriptObject.myFunction1(41);
     }
}
```

On application launch `myFunction1()` in `testjs.js` is called and it calls `someSlot` function in my QML as well but alert is not displayed. When `myFunction1()` function is called from the HTML page only `alert` is displayed and `someSlot` function is not called.

Comment: What do you mean by calling a Qml function? Do you want to invoke a method on some instance of a class? Simply give that class an `id`, then invoke the method as `id.method_name`. The documentation contains a plenty of examples.

Comment: @skypjack I have modified my question. Can you please help.

Comment: `app.html` does not make sense at all. The app IT'S the qml files on which you operate via imperative JavaScript or declarative bindings. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `alert()` within QML as it is not mapped. You have two solutions:

1. use `console.log`
2. use a `BoxDialog` instantiated in QML, and launch it from JS.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use Qt's WebChannel. It is used to communicate between hosted HTML content and external resources using WebSockets. See this for more information:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-index.html